Vuetify 3.x replacement for v-list-item-action-text
I've just upgraded to Vuetify 3.x and just realized that they removed v-list-item-action-text with no mention of it in the documentation. Does anybody have a working replacement for this? For reference in the picture (pulled directly from the 2.x docs), the v-list-item-action-text is the timestamp on the top right corner of each item.


It indeed looks like it was removed, given this page.
I checked their Github and Discord and apparently, if it's not there anymore, it was removed is what people agree on saying.
An alternative solution would be to use slots or CSS to do it yourself, no magic trick there. It was probably a bit too niche to have its own prop.
PS: here is a pending feature request for this feature, which leads me to think that it is a thing of the past.
